# Checkbox for many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class PlayerProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :playing_roles
  has_many :player_roles, through: :playing_roles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :playing_roles, :allow_destroy => true

end

class PlayingRole < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :player_roles
      belongs_to :player_profile
 end

class PlayerRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playing_roles
  has_many :player_profiles, through: :playing_roles
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
    create_table "player_profiles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.string   "favorite_team"
    t.string   "mobile"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "lang"
    t.string   "team"
    t.integer  "weight"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.text     "biography"
    t.string   "idols"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "nationality"
  end
  add_index "player_profiles", ["user_id"], name: "index_player_profiles_on_user_id", using: :btree
  create_table "player_roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
  create_table "playing_roles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "player_profile_id"
    t.integer  "player_role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I need to show checkboxes for each roles that a Player can playing. A checkbox checked means a record on "playing_roles" relashionship

Using **collection_check_boxes:** in Rails4

**UPDATE**

If I use **:playing_role_ids** I get this error:

```
<%=collection_check_boxes(:player_profile, :playing_role_ids, PlayerRole.all, :id, :name)%>
```

[image]

It seems that it's looking for the record on the relationship, but if a record doesn't exist it means there isn't a relationship and the checkbox must be unchecked.

Comment: are you using something like simpleform or formtastic? Or normal rails form helpers?

Comment: Normal rails helpers. Formstatic/simpleform could be better for this case?

Comment: I added a hint to my answer

Answer (score 9):

In Rails 3.x, use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

```
<%= simple_form_for @player_profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :player_roles, as: :check_boxes %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In Rails 4, using `collection_check_boxes` write

```
<%=collection_check_boxes(:player_profile, :playing_role_ids, PlayerRole.all, :id, :name)%>
```

You have to use the name `:playing_role_ids` because you are assigning IDs and not PlayingRoles.

Comment: I've tried with last edits but I get errors. Question updated

Comment: Sorry, wrong plural, it's `playing_role_ids`, singular playing_role, plural ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4, you should be able to use `collection_check_boxes`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes