# ambiguous column name for a many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create checkboxes for many to many relationship.

A `project` can have many `graphs`. A `graph` can belong to many `projects`.

I'm following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435937/checkbox-for-many-to-many-relationship), and using collection_check_boxes().

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:project, :user_graph_ids, UserGraph.all, :id, :title) %>
```

The result is a SQL error about ambiguous columns. Why is this occurring?

```
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: 
  SELECT "user_graphs".id 
  FROM "user_graphs" 
  INNER JOIN "project_user_graphs" 
  ON "user_graphs"."id" = "project_user_graphs"."user_graph_id" 
  WHERE "project_user_graphs"."project_id" = ?  
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the ordering of `UserGraph.all` to use `created_at` from the `user_graphs` table:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:project, :user_graph_ids, UserGraph.all.order("user_graphs.created_at ASC"), :id, :title) %>
```

NOTE: I'd eventually push this into the `UserGraph` model as a scope:

```
class UserGraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.ordered(direction="asc")
    order("user_graphs.created_at #{direction}")
  end
end

<%= collection_check_boxes(:project, :user_graph_ids, UserGraph.all.ordered, :id, :title) %>
```

Comment: still doesn't work with the top change. I assumed you forgot the close paranethesis after `ASC"`:

`<%= collection_check_boxes(:project, :user_graph_ids, UserGraph.all.order("user_graphs.created_at ASC"), :id, :title) %>` - the error is the same

Comment: It's interesting that us specifiying the order of UserGraph didn't affect the SQL query. Maybe the query is automatically created by the association between Project + UserGraph?

Comment: Strange.  Can you post the association that's in the `UserGraph` model?

Comment: Yea editing the question now, btw with your new code it gives this error `wrong number of arguments (3 for 5..7)` still looks like the paranthesis is in the wrong place :P